# How to remotely query for my questions, answers, upvotes and stars?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I keep searching for my upvotes and questions across several SE sites and was wondering if there is a way to **remotely** query for these actions to build an offline repository (a single web page, actually)?

I know about the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/#) but as far as I can see one cannot make remote calls (?).

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can download a [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)—it has the same data as Data Explorer.